# airflow 2.0.2 does not support task_group

Tags: task, airflow, group

I'm using airflow version 2.0.2 (MWAA and local install)

However, i can't import below packages.

- from airflow.decorators import task_group
- from airflow.utils.task_group import TaskGorup

Why?

The official doc says it works..
https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.0.2/_modules/airflow/example_dags/example_task_group.html

Comment: Please add traceback of the error

Answer (score 0):

are you using pyCharm? when installing package apache-airflow try selecting specify version to True, and selecting version 2.3.4.